# Rounding miliseconds

Tags: r, lubridate

I'm unsuccessfully trying to round my time column from showing miliseconds to just showing `hms`
I have tried to make it work with `floor_date()` and `round_date()` but without any luck.
Anyone knows how to round my miliseconds to whole seconds?

All help is much appreciated!

```
df <- structure(list(date = c("2020-12-15", "2020-12-15", "2020-12-15"
), time = c("09:19:26.599", "09:19:30.391", "09:19:31.142")), row.names = c(NA, 
-3L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this in base R with `as.POSIXct`

```
transform(df, datetime = round(as.POSIXct(paste(date, time), tz = 'UTC')))

#        date         time            datetime
#1 2020-12-15 09:19:26.599 2020-12-15 09:19:27
#2 2020-12-15 09:19:30.391 2020-12-15 09:19:30
#3 2020-12-15 09:19:31.142 2020-12-15 09:19:31
```

---

Using `dplyr` and `lubridate` :

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% mutate(datetime = round(lubridate::ymd_hms(paste(date, time))))
```